# Google Sheets: API To Get Crypto Prices and History?

Tags: google-sheets, cryptocurrency

As GOOGLEFINANCE() seems *very* limited in the cryptocurrencies it supports, are there any (free?) APIs that I can use to get data from?

Although I use GF() for ETH and BTC, I'm specifically looking for Price and Historical Closing Prices on **ADA** (Cardano).

I've searched the forum for suggestions, there aren't many and most are old. Binance's API seemed OK, but it gives prices in USDT instead of USD.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I found an API that offers a free key, although limited in the number of daily calls you can make: [CoinAPI](https://www.coinapi.io/).

It seems very powerful, with quotes available in most currencies. So far, I've managed to get a current price:
[image]
*Formulas shown in brown.*

(1) shows the raw data returned, a two rows delimited by semi-colons.

(2) wraps a QUERY() around IMPORTDATA(), using `offset 1` plus param 0, to not return the header row, then wraps all that in SPLIT() to separate the delimited text into columns.

(3) wraps (2) with INDEX() so I can get just the Price in the 4th col.

As this value will not automatically update like GOOGLEFINANCE(), I think I'll need to set a Trigger to do that.

I've also retrieved historical data, but I've yet to figure out how to split multiple rows of delimited text from the IMPORTDATA() function.

[Edit] See the solution to splitting multiple rows by @player0 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69055990/190925.