# Google Sheets: Split Multiple Rows of Delimited Text from IMPORTDATA()

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, import, split, google-sheets-formula

I'm getting historical data for a cryptocurrency using an API from [CoinAPI](https://www.coinapi.io/) which returns multiple rows, but each row consists of delimited text:

[image]

In the second formula I added SPLIT(), but it only returns the first row, which in this case is the headers.

I've previously returned data for *just* a current price using a combination of INDEX( SPLIT( QUERY( IMPORTDATA() ))), but that was only splitting one row in the end.

Is there a way to split all the rows using one formula, in one cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("url_here"), ";"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used INDEX, but not in this way! Cheers, Max

Comment: Hmmm,  I found that the docs are incomplete, as IMPORTDATA takes 3 params, not one as shown at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335.
They are: url, delimiter, locale. So I didn't need to use SPLIT  and INDEX at all.